# What is the best way to write an arbitrary multi-variable function?

Tags: discussion, formatting

I have been a bit confused for a while on what is the best way to write a multi-variable function of an arbitrary number of input variables when writing a question or answer. My first thought is to write it as a function of a vector $f(\vec{x})$, but this somewhat conflicts with the notion that the input to a multi-variable function is a point, not a vector. This seems to be how it's taught in most multi-variable calculus classes, so writing it as a function of a vector might confuse the asker and/or lead them to incorrectly believe that points and vectors are interchangeable.

I considered explicitly saying something like "Where $\vec{x}$ is a vector from the origin to the point", but that seems too wordy. I also considered $f(x_1,x_2,...)$, but I'm not a fan of ellipsis notation (not sure if anyone else feels this way, or if it's just a quirk of mine).

So what is the best notation for it?

Comment: I tend to use boldface myself: $f(\mathbf x)$ (scalar-valued) or $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf x)$ (vector-valued).

Comment: Just write $f(x)$.

Comment: As with a similar question that was posted on meta a while ago, I don't see why this was not posted on the main site.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I figured this was the right place for it because it pertains to how to best write a post.

Comment: It pertains to how to write math. That that math will be in a post is quite irrelevant :-) Do you expect that there is a different «best way» to write multi-variable functions in other mediums?

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Oh ok. Good to know!